# MVC Multiple FileUpload with a dynamic model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, file-upload

I'm afraid I'm totally new to MVC and almost as new to programming in general.

I have been making a questionnaire using MVC. Each user, upon logging in, is given a specific questionnaire generated from some data in a database. The View is bound to a Model containing a bunch of information and a list of Questions. The Questions are handled by an editor template consisting of many question related information such as ID, Name, Response or Type. One or more of these Questions could involve performing a file upload of one or more files.

I found this on stackoverflow: [MVC3, multiple file upload, model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637497/mvc3-multiple-file-upload-model-binding) which looked promising but as the number of file upload Questions can vary, I don't know how to match the uploaded files to the question ID. The approach here seems to involve using the name on the uploads to match them, but as I don't know how many upload Questions there will be, each will be generated and named dynamically on the page.

I managed to get it working if each question only allowed for one file to be uploaded, by adding a HttpPostedFileBase property to the questions, but I can't suss out how to allow any number of uploads.

In summary: is there any way to have 0+ file upload instances, each capable of uploading 1 or more files, and being able to tell which files belong to which upload Question?

In addition, if I wanted to submit my questionnaire using AJAX, would I have to use a separate jquery plugin (I've seen a couple mentioned) and handle the file uploads separately?

Apologies if the above doesn't make sense, I've become quite confused by the whole thing. I've not included any code as everything I've got is complicated and long :(

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recently completed a very similar project. I used the Fine File Uploader for JQuery. That took care of the uploaded mechanism itself. But I think you are asking about how to associate the files with the questions AFTER the upload.

If I understood your question correctly, you can do all of this dynamically by assigning an ID to each question (which I assume you already have) and then associating each uploaded file with its question ID in a session variable. This variable should be an appropriate data structure like a list. For example, each list item can be an object of type UploadedQuestionFile (defined by you) with 2 fields: QuestionID and FilePath. Of course, I'm simplifying the scenario a little to make it clear.

For the second question, yes, you should handle each file uploaded separately with an upload function defined in your controller. This function should read in the question ID and file from the request and associate them together in the session variable. Each file is handled separately because they are uploaded one at a time.

This should easily handle your requirements. Let me know if you need further explanation.